# How to get value from handler using Javascript in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, .net, c#-4.0, dom-events

How to get value from handler using Javascript in asp.net?

I have to upload image from handler using Javascript:

```
$j("form").submit(function () {
                document.getElementById('wLogoId').setAttribute('src', 'FileUpload.ashx?f=' + parseInt(hdn));
            });
$j("form").trigger('submit');
```